# Hadoop Hive Data can't be seen in table / but present at hdfs location

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created an External Table , specified it hdfs location.
I use insert/overwrite query (insert into table tabley select * from tablex)
data gets populated at hdfs location 
but while I try to check values using
select * from tabley

I don't get any values.

What could be the possible flaw ??

Comment: It might be the database issue. You are writing the data to a different database and reading from different database.
Please give the exact query which you ran. That will be helpful to figure out the things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some debugging pointers:

- You have configured the OutputFormat correctly since you are able to write the data. But you may not have the correct input format.
- Is the data text/csv? If so have you specified the correct column delimiter?
- Is there a mapreduce generated? try using select * from tab where true. If MR is generated check the Map Input records & output records.

Hope this helps. You can post the create table DDL.

Comment: Got it.  Input format was not correct . So data was present but not getting populated.